# Importing a JS library installed as a Node module

Tags: javascript, html, cors, node-modules, directory-structure

I want to set up a project using the [Britecharts](https://britecharts.github.io/britecharts/index.html) library. Having installed Britecharts with `npm install --save britecharts d3-selection` I'm trying to verify that the imports are working by displaying a basic chart in the browser.

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <!-- TESTME -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/britecharts/dist/css/britecharts.min.css">
  <script type="module" src="chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bar-container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

My chart.js:

```
// For ES modules
import bar from 'britecharts/dist/umd/bar.min';

// Instantiate bar chart and container
const barChart = britecharts.bar();
const container = d3.select('.bar-container');

// Create Dataset with proper shape
const barData = [
    { name: 'Luminous', value: 2 },
    { name: 'Glittering', value: 5 },
    { name: 'Intense', value: 4 },
    { name: 'Radiant', value: 3 }
];

// Configure chart
barChart
    .margin({left: 100})
    .isHorizontal(true)
    .height(400)
    .width(600);

container.datum(barData).call(barChart);
```

My folder stucture:

```
├── britecharts
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
├── chart.js
└── index.html
```

The dev console gives me this error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///Users/vahagnhay/Desktop/britecharts-test/chart.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).

I'm a newbie to JS projects — am I even doing this right?

Comment: The `file://` URL is suspect... How are you running this?  Are you opening a local URL served by a local web server, or just opening the HTML file from the file system into the browser?

Comment: It's the latter, just opening a file on my HD into the browser! That's why I don't get the CORS stuff.

Comment: That's the issue then.  You'll want to run this in a local web server so your code can make AJAX requests.  You can set up a server manually, or even just use a built-in debugging server in an IDE.  But just opening a file locally significantly limits what it can do.

Comment: So basically, there is no simple way to create a project with HTML, CSS, and JS files — only a complex way? For God's sake, the Javascript ecosystem makes web development painful. Why would I need to make AJAX requests for this?

Comment: @fullstackplus It's nothing to do with whether you do or don't use AJAX. It's just how the main browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox et el) work for security reasons. Most IDE's have plugins available for simple web servers. Some even have them backed in by default.

Comment: @fullstackplus But yes, JS ecosystem can be quite painful I agree. Either way running your app on a simple web server is just what you have to do in 2021. A common one a lot of people use for exactly this is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Thank you, have moved all files to a Sinatra app and am not getting the CORS error anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this. Forget all about Node imports and doing it "the JavaScript way" (I don't know why JavaScript people always feel they have to re-invent working conventions).

Instead, do it the Web Standards way. Unpack the Britecharts library files plus dependencies, put them in a folder local to your app, then import them in your HTML:

```
  <!-- chart -->
  <div class="bar-container"></div>

  <script src="/js/britecharts/node_modules/britecharts/dist/umd/bar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/britecharts/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"></script>

  <script src="/js/chart.js"></script>
  <!-- chart -->
```

Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

When loading a JS module you need to explicitly use a relative path. Eg `./chart.js`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

[EDIT] In addition, you need to run off a server (either locally or remotely). Again, see the MDN module link above.

> You need to pay attention to local testing — if you try to load the HTML file locally (i.e. with a `file://` URL), you'll run into CORS errors due to JavaScript module security requirements. You need to do your testing through a server.

Comment: Modified path to relative, no difference. Frefox says `Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///Users/vahagnhay/Desktop/britecharts-test/chart.js”.`

Comment: Actually, other comments are correct. Module loading won't work using a "file://" path (i.e. loading locally). It must be done via http(s). So you'll either need to spin up a local server on your dev machine, or upload to a remote server for testing.